# MySQL add new LIST partition based on passed id in stored proc?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

Thank you for taking a look.
I have a table with LIST partitioning. We need to have each client in its own partition:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`test` (
`client_id` INT NOT NULL,
`client_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`));

ALTER TABLE test PARTITION BY LIST (client_id)
(partition p100 values in (100),
partition p101 values in (101));
```

I am trying to create a stored procedure to be called when a new client is created:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `mydb`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `util_partioning_partition_new`(IN p_client_id INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE partition_name varchar(25);
select CONCAT('p', p_client_id) into partition_name;
ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION (PARTITION partition_name values in (p_client_id));
END$$

DELIMITER ;
;
```

and getting this error:
**Error 1064: Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed near** 'p_client_id));

PLEASE HELP! How do I pass client ID to the values in()?

Many thanks in advance,

Somebody on another forum (sorry for cross-post) suggested to use PREPARE.

So I tried the following but getting **Error Code: 1564**. This partition function is not allowed

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `mydb`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `util_partioning_partition_new`(IN p_client_id INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE partition_name varchar(25);
SELECT CONCAT('p', p_client_id) INTO partition_name;

PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION (PARTITION partition_name VALUES IN (?));';
SET @nid = p_client_id;

EXECUTE stmt1 USING @nid;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
;
```

Comment: "We need to have each client in its own partition:" -- Why?  There are many possible answers; some are bogus.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not expanded inside `ALTER TABLE` statements.

You can only use placeholders where expressions are allowed, but parameters in `ALTER TABLE` have to be constants.

So you have to use concatenation to get all your dynamic values into the statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `util_partioning_partition_new`(IN p_client_id INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE partition_name varchar(25);
    SET partition_name = CONCAT('p', p_client_id);
    SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION (PARTITION ', partition_name, ' VALUES in (', p_client_id, '))';
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END$$
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer!